# Using KMS encryption context with AWS S3 SDK for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3

I am trying to implement a POC involving document encryption using S3 SSE using AWS:KMS mechanism. This document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html states that it is possible to specify both KMS Key Id and Encryption Context.

However, putObject function in JavaScript (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property) only supports KMS Key Id parameter. In fact, I grepped through the entire JS AWS-SDK for references to `x-amz-server-side-encryption-context` and can't find it anywhere. The entire SDK doesn't support that header.

Here is my code:

```
     const s3Params = {
        Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
        Key: objectID,
        ContentType: 'application/gzip',
        Body: objectString,
        Expires: new Date(expire * 1000),
        ServerSideEncryption: 'aws:kms',
        SSEKMSKeyId: 'My KMS Key ID'
    };
    await s3.putObject(s3Params).promise();
```

Am I using the right function? Is this feature supported in JavaScript SDK at all?